# Accidently deleted all my jupyter notebook data still showing data in jupyter Variables

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv, data-analysis

Hi i accidentelly deleted my jupyterlab notebook data
i was trying to save the data from ipynb into csv format
I used the command:

```
path = ('F:\jupyter Lab Projects\Automotive residual value.ipynb')
df.to_csv(path)
```

after i exeuted the command everything vanished from my ipynb notebook i tried to revert the commad by doing ctrl + z but nothing happend
But i can see my data in a jupyter Variable section located below right side of terminal section.
I am using VSCODE and anaconda library
Please help me f anyone knows how to recover the data i really work hard to create that data.
thanks in advance.

I tried to revert the command by pressing ctrl+ z but nothing happened

AS i told you earlier data is showing in jupyter variables but not in notebook so there night be a chance to recover it as notebook
here is the link for the notebook.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tfi7vXuC_JAvsB7lLMvxeQRrJGPks2gA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try downloadig your dotepad as a `.ipynb`file and then viw it as a text file in a text editor (open with editor).

Using that, I got those values. Is that what you need?:

```
,symboling,normalized-losses,make,fuel-type,aspiration,num-of-doors,body-style,drive-wheels,engine-location,wheel-base,length,width,height,curb-weight,engine-type,num-of-cylinders,engine-size,fuel-system,bore,stroke,compression-ratio,horsepower,peak-rpm,city-mpg,highway-mpg,price,city-L/100KM,horsepower-binned
0,3.0,122.0,alfa-romero,gas,std,two,convertible,rwd,front,88.6,168.8,64.1,48.8,2548.0,dohc,four,130.0,mpfi,3.47,2.68,9.0,111,5000.0,21.0,27.0,13495.0,11.19047619047619,Low
1,3.0,122.0,alfa-romero,gas,std,two,convertible,rwd,front,88.6,168.8,64.1,48.8,2548.0,dohc,four,130.0,mpfi,3.47,2.68,9.0,111,5000.0,21.0,27.0,16500.0,11.19047619047619,Low
2,1.0,122.0,alfa-romero,gas,std,two,hatchback,rwd,front,94.5,171.2,65.5,52.4,2823.0,ohcv,six,152.0,mpfi,2.68,3.47,9.0,154,5000.0,19.0,26.0,16500.0,12.368421052631579,Medium
3,2.0,164.0,audi,gas,std,four,sedan,fwd,front,99.8,176.6,66.2,54.3,2337.0,ohc,four,109.0,mpfi,3.19,3.4,10.0,102,5500.0,24.0,30.0,13950.0,9.791666666666666,Low
4,2.0,164.0,audi,gas,std,four,sedan,4wd,front,99.4,176.6,66.4,54.3,2824.0,ohc,five,136.0,mpfi,3.19,3.4,8.0,115,5500.0,18.0,22.0,17450.0,13.055555555555555,Low
5,2.0,122.0,audi,gas,std,two,sedan,fwd,front,99.8,177.3,66.3,53.1,2507.0,ohc,five,136.0,mpfi,3.19,3.4,8.5,110,5500.0,19.0,25.0,15250.0,12.368421052631579,Low
6,1.0,158.0,audi,gas,std,four,sedan,fwd,front,105.8,192.7,71.4,55.7,2844.0,ohc,five,136.0,mpfi,3.19,3.4,8.5,110,5500.0,19.0,25.0,17710.0,12.368421052631579,Low
7,1.0,122.0,audi,gas,std,four,wagon,fwd,front,105.8,192.7,71.4,55.7,2954.0,ohc,five,136.0,mpfi,3.19,3.4,8.5,110,5500.0,19.0,25.0,18920.0,12.368421052631579,Low
8,1.0,158.0,audi,gas,turbo,four,sedan,fwd,front,105.8,192.7,71.4,55.9,3086.0,ohc,five,131.0,mpfi,3.13,3.4,8.3,140,5500.0,17.0,20.0,23875.0,13.823529411764707,Medium
9,2.0,192.0,bmw,gas,std,two,sedan,rwd,front,101.2,176.8,64.8,54.3,2395.0,ohc,four,108.0,mpfi,3.5,2.8,8.8,101,5800.0,23.0,29.0,16430.0,10.217391304347826,Low
10,0.0,192.0,bmw,gas,std,four,sedan,rwd,front,101.2,176.8,64.8,54.3,2395.0,ohc,four,108.0,mpfi,3.5,2.8,8.8,101,5800.0,23.0,29.0,16925.0,10.217391304347826,Low
11,0.0,188.0,bmw,gas,std,two,sedan,rwd,front,101.2,176.8,64.8,54.3,2710.0,ohc,six,164.0,mpfi,3.31,3.19,9.0,121,4250.0,21.0,28.0,20970.0,11.19047619047619,Medium
12,0.0,188.0,bmw,gas,std,four,sedan,rwd,front,101.2,176.8,64.8,54.3,2765.0,ohc,six,164.0,mpfi,3.31,3.19,9.0,121,4250.0,21.0,28.0,21105.0,11.19047619047619,Medium
13,1.0,122.0,bmw,gas,std,four,sedan,rwd,front,103.5,189.0,66.9,55.7,3055.0,ohc,six,164.0,mpfi,3.31,3.19,9.0,121,4250.0,20.0,25.0,24565.0,11.75,Medium
14,0.0,122.0,bmw,gas,std,four,sedan,rwd,front,103.5,189.0,66.9,55.7,3230.0,ohc,six,209.0,mpfi,3.62,3.39,8.0,182,5400.0,16.0,22.0,30760.0,14.6875,Medium
15,0.0,122.0,bmw,gas,std,two,sedan,rwd,front,103.5,193.8,67.9,53.7,3380.0,ohc,six,209.0,mpfi,3.62,3.39,8.0,182,5400.0,16.0,22.0,41315.0,14.6875,Medium
16,0.0,122.0,bmw,gas,std,four,sedan,rwd,front,110.0,197.0,70.9,56.3,3505.0,ohc,six,209.0,mpfi,3.62,3.39,8.0,182,5400.0,15.0,20.0,36880.0,15.666666666666666,Medium
17,2.0,121.0,chevrolet,gas,std,two,hatchback,fwd,front,88.4,141.1,60.3,53.2,1488.0,l,three,61.0,2bbl,2.91,3.03,9.5,48,5100.0,47.0,53.00000000000001,5151.0,5.0,Low
18,1.0,98.0,chevrolet,gas,std,two,hatchback,fwd,front,94.5,155.9,63.6,52.0,1874.0,ohc,four,90.0,2bbl,3.03,3.11,9.6,70,5400.0,38.0,43.0,6295.0,6.184210526315789,Low
19,0.0,81.0,chevrolet,gas,std,four,sedan,fwd,front,94.5,158.8,63.6,52.0,1909.0,ohc,four,90.0,2bbl,3.03,3.11,9.6,70,5400.0,38.0,43.0,6575.0,6.184210526315789,Low
20,1.0,118.0,dodge,gas,std,two,hatchback,fwd,front,93.7,157.3,63.8,50.8,1876.0,ohc,four,90.0,2bbl,2.97,3.23,9.41,68,5500.0,37.0,41.0,5572.0,6.351351351351352,Low
21,1.0,118.0,dodge,gas,std,two,hatchback,fwd,front,93.7,157.3,63.8,50.8,1876.0,ohc,four,90.0,2bbl,2.97,3.23,9.4,68,5500.0,31.0,38.0,6377.0,7.580645161290323,Low
22,1.0,118.0,dodge,gas,turbo,two,hatchback,fwd,front,93.7,157.3,63.8,50.8,2128.0,ohc,four,98.0,mpfi,3.03,3.39,7.6,102,5500.0,24.0,30.0,7957.0,9.791666666666666,Low
23,1.0,148.0,dodge,gas,std,four,hatchback,fwd,front,93.7,157.3,63.8,50.6,1967.0,ohc,four,90.0,2bbl,2.97,3.23,9.4,68,5500.0,31.0,38.0,6229.0,7.580645161290323,Low
24,1.0,148.0,dodge,gas,std,four,sedan,fwd,front,93.7,157.3,63.8,50.6,1989.0,ohc,four,90.0,2bbl,2.97,3.23,9.4,68,5500.0,31.0,38.0,6692.0,7.580645161290323,Low
25,1.0,148.0,dodge,gas,std,four,sedan,fwd,front,93.7,157.3,63.8,50.6,1989.0,ohc

and a lot more lines..
```

As your file provided in the google-colab link is broken, we can't extract more than that out of it.

Comment: Thanks a alot man but thats not the data i am looking for, there was an entire notebook filled with visualization and markdown codes and explaination codes along with analysis. i guess i converting the ipynb into csv format thats why it deleted all the visualization and markdows. Only thing remains is the csv data. But i dont understand It is still in ipynb format then why everything vanished.

Comment: Well we can't extract more than this data from the link you provided, since the file you providedis corrupded. However, can't you just scrape all your variables within the notebook and save to a file?

Comment: I have the orignial data backedup into csv format but i lost all the visualization , regression and & markdown data. I guess i have to do it all over again.

Comment: Well in that case, I think so too, unfortanely.